# How do I publish a MEAN Stack App to work on a Rasperry Pi?

Tags: asp.net, node.js, asp.net-core, raspberry-pi, mean-stack

I have a MEAN Stack app running on ASP.NET on one port. That app starts a Node.js express server on a different Port. using the following command..

```
"dotnet-run": "concurrently \"dotnet run\" \"node server.js\" ",
```

..and all of it works perfectly in development mode on my Computer.

Now I'm trying to use the following command to publish it and use it on a Raspberry Pi with Debian:

```
dotnet publish -c debug -r linux-arm -o debug --self-contained
```

The App starts but the Node.Js Server does not.

Also I'm getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: vendor_ is not defined
```

I was using this Tutorial as a Guide : https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2018/04/17/hosting-an-asp-net-core-2-application-on-a-raspberry-pi/

So now to my Question: **What is considered best practice to publish such a MEAN Stack app with two servers running next to each other (to work on a Raspberry Pi)?**